# I answered a Facebook SDK problem that most people experience. Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-answer

The answer in question is [to *Facebook PHP-SDK: getUser() always returns 0*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14777070/434024). `getUser()` returning 0 isn't a specific problem. I wrote a walktrough on how to examine it and added solutions (also with answered links from Stack Overflow).

There are a lot of people asking the same question and questions weren't answered or solved(or weren't deleted, of course).

So I posted this answer on each question. My posts (all of them) were deleted. Why? I thought it might be useful for people who experience same problem.

Comment: Which was your answer? I don't have enough reputation to see deleted answers. Please post the content of it.

Comment: Ok,i have added content now.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri It's not really relevant; it's not a poor quality answer, it was deleted because he copy/pasted it to a lot of questions.

Comment: Do not place the content of your answer here.  You're spamming the site, and there's no reason to place it here.  There's more than enough people who have the reputation to see the deleted answers.

Comment: @casperOne Well, he did it because he was requested to here in comments, don't blame the OP.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough.  We have enough of that going on in other metas (and it's not necessary there), we don't need it here.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Please don't request that the contents of the answer be placed in the post.  It creates a lot of additional noise that's not necessary.  The content can always be placed in a gist or somewhere else and linked to from here.

Comment: @casperOne: But link-only posts are subject to link rot and all that jazz...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Not saying that the *post* should be solely a link, but placing the entire content of another post in the post is a lot of noise.  Fact of the matter is that the content *is* there, just not everyone can see it.  If we deleted it on the main site, it doesn't need to be *here*.

Comment: @casperOne Are you aware that I'm not able to see his answer anywhere? I can't see deleted posts, how am I supposed to help the OP?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I do understand that, but a meta post is not a place to replicate a post on the main site.  The comment about the content being placed somewhere else was more for others who would do it for you.

Answer (score 25):

You mean the one you [copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840533/facebook-getuser-always-returning-0/14776996#14776996) and [pasted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498713/why-is-getuser-always-returning-0/14776908#14776908) [across](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490411/facebook-getuser-always-returns-0/14776836#14776836) [six](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790316/getuser-always-returns-0-even-if-im-logged-in/14776697#14776697) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901688/getuser-always-returns-0/14776589#14776589) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661880/getuser-always-returning-0/14776499#14776499)?

Next time, find the single canonical question, post an answer there, and then flag/vote for the rest to be closed as duplicates of the canonical question.

Fact is, you were spamming your answer and that's something you shouldn't do.

Comment: That's a bingo!

Comment: seems horrible but isn't it good to leave one answer .. which is most appropriate to question ?

Comment: @NullPointer I would say yes, but generally, if someone is going to *that* much trouble to spam an answer, the primary concern is stopping that behavior and then sorting out the answer later.  We usually get copy-paste on the level of say, two answers.  When it's in the five-six (or higher) range, it's time to slash and burn.

Comment: @NullPointer Most of the questions the OP pasted on were already answered.  I see what you're saying though, so I closed a couple that were left with zero answers as duplicates.  I'm not much of a PHP dev, so I'm not the best person to pick the "canonical" question/answer, but this is better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks, my motivation was to help. However, i understand it now.

Comment: @fatihpense No problem, if there's a *single* one that you want undeleted, we can do that, and let us know which ones are duplicates, we'd appreciate that.

Comment: @fatihpense IMHO  you are just telling about possible case(have less probebality to happen) .. also this is not really a problem in fb api

Comment: @casperOne Actually i have gone through a lot of them searching for an answer before i have solved my problem, and posted my solution. Part of the problem is that askers can't give specific information. I have included how they can provide detailed information in my answer. Is it more appropriate to write these as comment to question?

Comment: @fatihpense yes, if they haven't defined the question well enough then ask them in a comment to provide more details.  That's what comments are for

Answer (score 10):

As a general rule if you find yourself posting the same answer on multiple questions then something is wrong.

There are really two cases here:

1. The questions are duplicates; the answer should be posted on the best question (or the newest, or the one you found first, or whatever, but ideally leave the highest quality question open) and the rest of the questions should be closed as a duplicate of that one answered question.  Post your answer once and then vote/flag the rest of the questions.
2. The questions are not duplicates, and your answer is not directly answering the question (even if it's related).  It usually means that the answer needs to be adapted to the specific context of the question, even if it's "pretty close" as is.

Then there's a third case in which the answers are all just blatantly offtopic/abusive/spam/etc. and just need to not exist at all, but that's clearly not the case here.

Comment: Thanks, i'm new here. I think, i should sit and read all those docs before helping.